# Get unix_timestamp for date in mysql

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have a column with type datetime with values that look like

```
id updated_at
1, 2015-03-04 18:49:41
2, 2016-05-24 19:28:43
3, 2014-07-29 19:15:44
```

The date stored in the database is in UTC timezone.

Now when i retrieve it, I want to retrieve it as UTC time, and convert that time to a unit_timestamp.

However, whenever i do

```
SELECT unix_timestamp(updated_at) from table
```

I think it auto added my local timezone when parsing the date and gave me a unix_timestamp that is ~ 4 hours (I am in Eastern time) off from the timestamp that i was expecting.

How should i approach this issue? I can obviously just remove the 4 hours offset, but things get tricky when some dates had a 5 hours offset due to daytimesaving stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ("some_date", '+00:00', 'SYSTEM'))
```